# $f:GL(2,\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is well defined

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

Consider the function $f:GL(2,\mathbb{R})\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^*$ defined by   $f(A)=|A|$. Prove that the map $f$ is well defined?

Comment: Define it well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it is well defined. Since $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ contains only invertible matrices, therefore for any matrix $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ we will have a unique real number $\det(A)$. Hence we can define the map $A\longmapsto \det(A)$, which is well defined.